# How do I add JCheckBox next to each name that has been entered into an arraylist from a JTextField?

Tags: java, user-interface, arraylist, jtextfield, jcheckbox

I am creating a ManageUsers GUI which will look like this:

[image]

**I want the checkboxes to go next to the names in a list that were entered from the Add New User section.** I know that most of it is not done  but Here's what i have so far:

AddUsers

```
public class AddUsers {

   private String userName;

   public AddUsers(String userName) {
      this.userName = userName;
   }

   public AddUsers() {
      userName = "";
   }   

   public void setUserName(String userName) {
      this.userName = userName;   
   }

   public String getUserName() {
      return userName;
   }

   public String toString() {
      return userName + "\n";
   }

}
```

ManageUsersGUI

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.awt.TextField;


public class ManageUsersGUI1 extends JPanel {
    public static ArrayList<AddUsers> users = new ArrayList<>();

    private JLabel addNewUserLabel;
    private JTextField addNewUserTextField;
    private JLabel deleteUsersLabel;
    private JCheckBox jcomp4;
    private JCheckBox jcomp5;
    private JCheckBox jcomp6;
    private JButton addButton;
    private JButton deleteButton;

    public ManageUsersGUI1() {         
        //construct components
        addNewUserLabel = new JLabel ("Add new User here:");
        addNewUserTextField = new JTextField (0);
        deleteUsersLabel = new JLabel ("Select which User(s) you would like to delete:");
        jcomp4 = new JCheckBox ("newCheckBox");
        jcomp5 = new JCheckBox ("newCheckBox");
        jcomp6 = new JCheckBox ("newCheckBox");
        addButton = new JButton ("Add");
        deleteButton = new JButton ("Delete");

        //set components properties
        addNewUserTextField.setToolTipText ("Enter name and click on Add button.");
        addButton.setToolTipText ("Click here to Add new user.");
        deleteButton.setToolTipText ("Click here to delete User(s) selected.");

        //adjust size and set layout
        setPreferredSize (new Dimension (580, 485));
        setLayout (null);

        //add components
        add (addNewUserLabel);
        add (addNewUserTextField);
        add (deleteUsersLabel);
        add (jcomp4);
        add (jcomp5);
        add (jcomp6);
        add (addButton);
        add (deleteButton);

        //set component bounds (only needed by Absolute Positioning)
        addNewUserLabel.setBounds (85, 130, 120, 25);
        addNewUserTextField.setBounds (235, 130, 125, 25);
        deleteUsersLabel.setBounds (135, 225, 281, 25);
        jcomp4.setBounds (225, 270, 140, 25);
        jcomp5.setBounds (225, 300, 140, 25);
        jcomp6.setBounds (225, 330, 140, 25);
        addButton.setBounds (385, 130, 100, 25);
        deleteButton.setBounds (230, 410, 100, 25);

        addButton.addActionListener(new AddButtonListener());

    }

    private class AddButtonListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           String text = addNewUserTextField.getText();
           users.add(new AddUsers(text));

           // Display the charges.
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, text + " has been added.");
        }
   }


    public static void main (String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame ("AddUsersPanel1");
        frame.setTitle("Manage Users");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add (new ManageUsersGUI1());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible (true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked into adding the checkbox dynamically when on a click-listener? In Android you can dynamically add a checkbox view and set its title and ID, then use that to reference the relevant data...

Comment: Unfortunately i will not be using this program on Android. It is just a brief project that will be run on desktop. @FrankBrenyah

Comment: My point is it is still Java and there are still listeners, and there are still checkboxes and you can dynamically add a checkbox on an event callback (like a button press). Issue here is that I am not sure how to draw it exactly where you want it...but I am sure you can work that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `JPanel` with `BoxLayout` as the layout manager.

That way, for each new name entered in the `JTextField`, you can add a new `JCheckBox` to the `JPanel` and it automatically lists lays them out in order vertically.

I've made some modifications to your code to exemplify, so you can adjust to your needs:

```
public class ManageUsersGUI1 extends JPanel {
    public static ArrayList<AddUsers> users = new ArrayList<>();

    private JLabel addNewUserLabel;
    private JTextField addNewUserTextField;
    private JLabel deleteUsersLabel;
    private JButton addButton;
    private JButton deleteButton;
    private JPanel namePanel;

    public ManageUsersGUI1() {
        //construct components
        addNewUserLabel = new JLabel ("Add new User here:");
        addNewUserTextField = new JTextField (0);
        deleteUsersLabel = new JLabel ("Select which User(s) you would like to delete:");
        addButton = new JButton ("Add");
        deleteButton = new JButton ("Delete");
        namePanel = new JPanel();
        namePanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(namePanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        //set components properties
        addNewUserTextField.setToolTipText ("Enter name and click on Add button.");
        addButton.setToolTipText ("Click here to Add new user.");
        deleteButton.setToolTipText ("Click here to delete User(s) selected.");

        //adjust size and set layout
        setPreferredSize (new Dimension (580, 485));
        setLayout (null);

        //add components
        add (addNewUserLabel);
        add (addNewUserTextField);
        add (deleteUsersLabel);
        add (namePanel);
        add (addButton);
        add (deleteButton);

        //set component bounds (only needed by Absolute Positioning)
        addNewUserLabel.setBounds (85, 130, 120, 25);
        addNewUserTextField.setBounds (235, 130, 125, 25);
        deleteUsersLabel.setBounds (135, 225, 281, 25);
        addButton.setBounds (385, 130, 100, 25);
        namePanel.setBounds(225, 270, 140, 0);
        deleteButton.setBounds (230, 335, 100, 25);

        addButton.addActionListener(new AddButtonListener());

    }

    private class AddButtonListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String text = addNewUserTextField.getText();
            users.add(new AddUsers(text));

            // Display the charges.
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, text + " has been added.");

            JCheckBox nameCheckBox = new JCheckBox();
            nameCheckBox.setText(addNewUserTextField.getText());
            namePanel.add(nameCheckBox);
            namePanel.setBounds(225, 270, 140, namePanel.getHeight() + 25);
            deleteButton.setBounds(230, deleteButton.getY() + 25, 100, 25);
            JFrame frame = (JFrame) getRootPane().getParent();
            frame.setSize(frame.getWidth(), frame.getHeight() + 25);
            frame.pack();
        }
    }


    public static void main (String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame ("AddUsersPanel1");
        frame.setTitle("Manage Users");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add (new ManageUsersGUI1());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible (true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! that is exactly what I wanted. Now the only problem I have is that when I press the delete button after I checked some of the names, it does not delete. When i try to start a private class for a `DeleteButtonListener` it gives me an error of `ManageUsersGUI1.java:80: error: ManageUsersGUI1.DeleteButtonListener is not abstract and does not override abstract method actionPerformed(ActionEvent) in ActionListener`

Comment: @pyuntae That seems like a new question. It seems to be concerned about the implementation of action listeners. Go ahead and create a new question, add some example code to it, and the stack trace.

Comment: @pyuntae I understand your question. It has a simple answer: `ActionListeners` are "incomplete" classes, which means you have to implement the missing functions. The error you are getting is complaining that you didn't implement those classes and you didn't mark the class as "incomplete" (abstract).